# Data binding - multiple attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I wanted to understand how multiple attributes are set in the child component when they are sent together from the parent.

```
<!-- Parent Opponent -->
<aura:attribute name="att1" type="String"/> 
<aura:attribute name="att2" type="String"/> 

<c:child attribute1="{!v.att1}" attribute2="{v.att2} />
```

I have used something similar in a component and it worked.

But it does not work for another component. So I am trying to understand the flow here.

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is not proper.   You forgot ! mark on att2.

```
<c:child attribute1="{!v.att1}" attribute2="{!v.att2} />
```